# Defining holomorphic branches on the complex domain with intervals removed

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to define a  holomorphic branch of $(z^2+1)^{1/2}$ on the complex domain on two domains.

In the first, the line segment from $-i$ to $i$ is removed.

In the second, the rays extending upwards from $i$ and downwards from $-i$ are removed.

I noticed by sort-of-coincidence that the branch $\exp \frac12 \textrm{Log} (z^2+1)$ happens to work for the latter case (where Log is the principal branch of the logarithm) but have no idea how to proceed with the former case.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what made the second case work is that on the rays $z^2+1$ was negative.  So use the fact that $-(z^2+1)$ is negative on the interval.  With the multivalued log, at all points outside of $i$, $-i$ we find
$$
\exp\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}\log(z^2+1)\Bigr)
=
\exp\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}\log\bigl((-1)(-(z^2+1)\bigr)\Bigr)
$$
$$
=
\exp\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}(\log(-1) + \log\bigl(-(z^2+1)\bigr)\Bigr)
=\exp\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}(\pi i + \log\bigl(-(z^2+1)\bigr)\Bigr)
$$
That's an equality of multivalued functions.
Now think about why that works and why taking the principal branch of the log gets you what you want.